# Cause of hidden margins?

Tags: css

I'm working on redoing someone's existing Weebly site.

It's not complete, but one problem I've run into is there's additional margin (I think margin) happening *in addition* to the margin I've already included.

The original site can be viewed here:
http://budaeva.weebly.com/index.html

The site redo can be viewed here:
http://backwards.ca/ayyyna/index.html

And the fiddle can be viewed here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mG5hW/

The area in question is below:

```
#feature_pic img
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the slight padding above and below the image?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Add `display: block` to `#feature_pic img`

Explanation.

By default `<img>` is an `inline` element, and thus the space is coming from the supposed `line-height`. But you need to change the `img` to display as a `block` level element.

Comment: Some browsers (mostly ie) like to add empty space below images that are not set to display:block. I think the actual space itself is an artifact of the line-height property inherent in non-block objects.

Comment: Good added explanation so +1. :)

Comment: The best explanation of the mysterious gaps below the images I've seen is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps